# SQL*Plus TNS:protocol adapter error

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am using this system on which everything was already configured. I want to connect to local db on SQL Plus. When I enter user-name scott and password tiger, it gives ORA-12560:TNS:protocol adapter error.

```
Enter user-name: scott
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

When I try with one line connection string scott/tiger@localhost:1521/orcl, it gives ORA-12541: TNS:no listener.

```
Enter user-name: scott/tiger@localhost:1521/orcl
ERROR:
ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
```

I am new to this.

Comment: Windows or Unix? Is the Instance running?

Comment: The " ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error" _almost_ always means 1) you are on a Windows, and 2) the environment variable ORACLE_SID is not set to the name of a database whose windows service is started.  That would also explain the ORA-12154.  Check that the service is started, in 'services.msc'.

Comment: yes, I am on windows. how to check oracle_sid is set or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle client throwing ORA-12541: TNS:no listener](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53380/oracle-client-throwing-ora-12541-tnsno-listener)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that oracleserviceSID is running in your services.msc.

Then try restart your listener from services.msc itself or from command prompt(connect to sqlplus sys as sysdba).

(Hope you have configured listener.ora from netca)